ffplay reading PCM data from pipe - pause when no data available instead of continuing to seek
I am using ffplay (and I suspect ffmpeg is also necessary somewhere in the pipeline) to play audio from an audio byte stream produced by a Python script, which may produce bytes (raw PCM16LE, single channel, 24khz) at an arbitrary interval.
My first attempt was to simply pipe the bytes to the ffplay subprocess:
ffplay = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ffplay", "-nodisp", "-f", "s16le", "-ar", "24000", "-acodec", "pcm_s16le", "-i", "-"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
)
# ...
for segment in audio_iter:
    ffplay.stdin.write(segment.raw_data)

However, what happens is that when the audio iterator is temporarily exhausted, ffplay continues to "seek" forward in time. Later, the audio stream might emit more bytes, which I expected to be played immediately, but what happens instead is that nothing is played until the audio bytes "catch up" to where the playhead has seeked to in ffplay, which results in some audio being lost.
I checked the ffplay docs and couldn't find any kind of behaviour regarding autopausing when the data stream is exhausted. I suspect it might be necessary to use ffmpeg to "fill in" empty data when no bytes are available from the Python stream, but here is where I'm getting lost. Is there some way to do this with ffmpeg piping into ffplay? My current attempt looks like this, but it has the same issue.
ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ffmpeg", "-f", "s16le", "-ar", "24000", "-ac", "1", "-i", "pipe:", "-f", "wav", "pipe:"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
)
ffplay = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ffplay", "-nodisp", "-i", "-"],
    stdin=ffmpeg.stdout,
    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
)
# ...
for segment in audio_iter:
    ffmpeg.stdin.write(segment.raw_data)

These two questions seemed relevant, but I also couldn't get them to output correctly (it ended up garbling up the input audio - I suspect as the raw PCM audio is not in realtime).
https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/148o6jb/inserting_silence_into_stream_when_stream_is/
Fill gaps in piped in audio with silence in FFMPEG
